# Making a UL wider than it's parent LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a nav bar with dropdown menus, I would like the dropdown menus to stretch to whatever width necessary for the content inside it, but they will only go as wide as their parent element

I've read quite a bit on this, and most people suggest setting position:absolute on the dropdown menus. I've already done this and it doesn't effect it

My jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqgh6/

Does anyone know how I can get it the dropdowns to go wider than their parent element?

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.However, now that I can allow the child element to be as wide as its contents, can I also allow it to be NO shorter width than it's parent li? So, I want the li's minimum width to be the width of the parent but also for li's width to be the width of the containing contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply add `white-space:nowrap;` to the `<a>` elements:

```
.menu ul a {font-size:12px;padding:0 10px;line-height:22px;text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;}
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqgh6/2/).

Comment: Thanks, always love the simple solutions :)

Comment: One more addition: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/Rqgh6/3/ — removed `float` from items and added `display:block` to `<a>`, so when there are long items the links would fill the ul's width.

Comment: Thanks kizu, that's exactly what I just did before reading that lol :)

Comment: shadow, it's a nice solution can you example me why white-space:nowrap; work here. thanks in advance :)

Comment: @sandeep it's forcing the element contents to not wrap to new lines, even when they normally should do that due to width of the parent element. It functions the same as wrapping the contents with `<nobr>` and `</nobr>` tags. Good explanation is also available here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html under "nowrap" section.