# Allowing a sub-menu to be larger than its parent without sacrificing layout?

Tags: html, css, menu, width, submenu

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175128/making-a-ul-wider-than-its-parent-li), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849124/make-submenu-dropdown-wider-than-parent-li). I tried to apply `whitespace: nowrap;` to my code, but had no luck. The second question I simply cannot discern what is relevant and what isn't.

I have this HTML:

```
<ul id="main-menu-list">
        <li><a class="box-link" href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="box-link" id="shop-link" href="#/shop">Shop</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="">Test</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">Test 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="linkData in coreCtrl.mainMenuData"><a class="box-link" href="#/{{ linkData.linkUrl }}">{{ linkData.value }}</a></li>
      </ul>
```

In that last bit I'm using Angular to create some links from JSON which don't have sub-menus.

I also have this CSS:

```
#main-menu-list, #main-menu-list ul {

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;

  }

  #main-menu-list > li {

    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 65px;

  }

  #main-menu-list > li > a {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #6e6e6e;
    border: 2px solid #6e6e6e;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

  }

  #main-menu-list > li > a:hover {

    border: 2px solid #a1b489;
    color: #a1b489;
    text-decoration: none;

  }

  #main-menu-list > li > ul > li {

    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 0;

  }

  #main-menu ul a {

    white-space: nowrap;

  }
```

The end goal here is to create a sub-menu for the "Shop" link which contains the shop's categories. However, the drop-down needs to be wider that the parent list item. I can increase the width of the sub-menu, but at the cost of increasing the width of the parent `<li>` element, which throws off the layout of the main menu.

Is there any way to make the sub-menu larger than the parent element without sacrificing the parent's layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would make the parent li relative positioned and the sub-nav absolute positioned, this should sort out your problem.

```
#main-menu-list li {position: relative;}
#main-menu-list li > ul {position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;}
```

Comment: Correct answer, Ankit answered first.

Comment: ha, minus the example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use css property `position : absolute` for the drop-down ul and `position : relative` for the parent ul
After that define top and width of the drop-down ul and it will work

Comment: Ahhh. I had interpreted thos questions to mean absolutely positioning the sub directory ul's children li elements, not the actual unordered list.

Comment: If your query has been resolved, you should accept the answer.